# docker: docker start fails after creating daemon.json

Tags: docker

I am trying to setup awslogs for docker.
The docs say to add this to daemon.json:

```
{
  "log-driver": "awslogs",
  "log-opts": {
    "awslogs-region": "eu-central-1"
  }
}
```

When I create on Ubuntu /etc/docker/daemon.json with the content above docker wont start again.

```
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Fr 2018-07-20 10:59:53 CEST; 11s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 647 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 647 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 20 10:59:53 dev01-ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Jul 20 10:59:53 dev01-ubuntu systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 20 10:59:53 dev01-ubuntu systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 20 10:59:53 dev01-ubuntu systemd[1]: docker.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 20 10:59:53 dev01-ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Jul 20 10:59:53 dev01-ubuntu systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jul 20 10:59:53 dev01-ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

Can anybody explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Not ever use it.

But from this: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/plugins/, it seems we need to install plugin for any new log driver, check it with `docker plugin ls`

Maybe it just available in amazon cloud environment, not available in local pc, just in case you did not notice that.